# NFS4 - Mounting multiple subdirs

Tags: linux, centos, nfs

I'm trying to setup 2 different mount points on an NFS4 server but can't get it working as desired.

```
/etc/exports (on server)

/mnt/raid/nas                   10.1.0.0/18(rw,fsid=0,sync)
/mnt/raid/nas/file/perm         10.1.0.0/18(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=501,anongid=503)
/mnt/raid/nas/mail              10.1.0.0/18(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=5555,anongid=5555)
```

With the above mount points, in theory I should be able to mount the subdirs, separately, like:

```
$ -> mount -v -t nfs4 nas.vpc1.j1n.us:/mnt/raid/nas/file/perm /mnt/nas/store/file/perm/
```

But I keep getting these errors: `... failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory`, but if I mount like this:

```
$ -> mount -v -t nfs4 nas.vpc1.j1n.us:/ /mnt/nas/
```

It works. But there are other dirs in the /mnt/raid/nas folder on the NFS server which I do not want to expose to NFS clients, so this option really doesn't help.

What can I do to use NFS4, but specify mount points so I don't end up sharing everything in /mnt/raid/nas?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix-Linux) OR http://ServerFault.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Comment: I know basically nothing about this but why do you include the `/mnt/raid/nas` path components in the first attempt but leave them out of the second attempt? I would have (naively) assumed they should either be in both or be left out of both.

Comment: The second attempt is what I picked up reading some online docs. Apparently with fsid=0 on the root, I can mount without specifying the path, but it does introduce the issue I spelled out in the OP, in that other dirs in `/mnt/raid/nas` are now exposed to clients after mounting.

Comment: Have you tried the crossmnt option?

Comment: I've seen that option but I don't think that would help in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Because I set `/mnt/nas` as fsid=0, that means that clients mounting subdirectories no longer need to reference the entire path, only the child subdirs (relative pathing).

Change this:

```
$ -> mount -v -t nfs4 nas.vpc1.j1n.us:/mnt/raid/nas/file/perm /mnt/nas/store/file/perm/
$ -> mount -v -t nfs4 nas.vpc1.j1n.us:/mnt/raid/nas/mail /mnt/nas/mail/
```

To this

```
$ -> mount -v -t nfs4 nas.vpc1.j1n.us:/file/perm /mnt/nas/store/file/perm/
$ -> mount -v -t nfs4 nas.vpc1.j1n.us:/mail /mnt/nas/mail/
```

Notice that in the 2nd set of commands the parent path `/mnt/raid/nas` is missing from the `server:/path` section of each command.